# A form of chain rule to differentiate the flow of a vector field on a manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading the proof for a theorem about connections on a manifold, but I'm not comfortable with the fancy language of vector bundles and flows of vector fields I think. I wonder if there's an easy way of understand this calculation using just multivariable calculus:

So, we have a fiber bundle $\pi: E \to M$ and for any $\gamma(t) \in M$ we have a family of diffeomorphisms that makes parallel transport possible: $P^t_{\gamma}: E_{x_0} \to E_{\gamma(t)}$.
It says that $P^t_{\gamma}$ is the flow of some vector field $Y(t,p)$ on the total space of the pullback bundle $\gamma^* E$ (what is that?)
Choosing any section $s: M \to E$ with $s(x_0)=p_0$ and writing $F(t,p) = (P^t_{\gamma})^{-1}(p)$, we have:

$$\nabla_{\dot \gamma(0)}s = \left.\frac{d}{dt}F(t,s(\gamma(t))) \right|_{t=0} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(0,p_0)+ D_2F(0,p_0) \circ Ts(\dot \gamma(0))=-Y(0,p_0)+Ts(\dot \gamma(0))$$

So, here is where I get confused. How does this differentiation work? It's easy to differentiate the first component of $F$ with respect to $t$ but the second one is complicated and I can't figure out how that works. Moreover, why $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} (0,p_o) = -Y(t,p)$?

Comment: without references, it sounds not appetizing to dig

Comment: @janmarqz: Here's the reference: http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahcwe/pub/connections_chapter3.pdf. Look at page 5.

Comment: ok, thanks, on these matters i would like to ask you if you already had studied differential geometry from the perspective of the standard connection (covariant derivative of ambient space IR^3) for curves and surfaces, do you?

Comment: @janmarqz: No, I haven't studied differential geometry unfortunately and now I am starting to regret that. This semester I'm going to have a course in differential manifolds (I already have had an introductory course to differential manifolds) and they are going to discuss connections, gauge transformations and similar mathematical concepts in that course and as far as I can see, I'm definitely not ready to understand connections on a manifold yet. Is there a way to understand what's going on with that calculation by the way?

Comment: I had suggested differential geometry as a starting point to understand connections but not every book on differential geometry use this approach, but the Noel Hicks' book is a good one, as well as Manfredo do Carmo's one. Both well suited for self study.

Comment: But do I need to self-study differential geometry before I understand why a simple question is differentiated like that? I think that's too much. Isn't it?

Comment: maybe be there are some other shortcuts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28822/discussion-between-h-z-and-janmarqz).